# inheriting from IdentityDbContext<T> slows down tests

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I had a run of the mill dbcontext I was using then I started to implement .net Identity (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework) and thought "oh look, its based on dbcontext, I'll just attach that to my existing context".

So this ...

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext {
    public SomeContext() : base("DefaultConnection"){ }
}
```

Simply turned to this ...

```
public class SomeContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {
    public SomeContext() : base("DefaultConnection") {}
}
```

All fine and good, the site runs perfectly with no problems at all... but the tests go from about 1 second to about 2 minutes.  If I switch it back it goes right back to the short test runs so I'm thinking I might be missing something or there's something else going on I'm not entirely aware of.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well an `IdentityDbContext` adds complexity but a lot depends on how you use it. Simply making this change without using any Identity specific functionality shouldn't cause such a difference. Have you used a profiler to see where it gets hung on? Are these tests in-memory or using an actual database?

Comment: I know right? What throws me the most -- its ~60 tests? All the dbset's are in mem via a helper method to stub out the Set<T> identical to this https://gist.github.com/jeriley/42f2a58300381e843ca0 but it DOES feel like it's checking the actual db before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change
`public SomeContext() : base("DefaultConnection") {}`
to
`public SomeContext() : base("DefaultConnection", false) {}`

This additional boolean will make `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` not check the connection for the identity tables.  That will speed up the tests.

Comment: Yeah, that throwIfV1Schema flag is a dark and stormy code path.